# Bootstrap Carousel next slide adds below the previous slide

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have added the bootstrap carousel in which the div **item** is created in the for loop shown below. I have **9** small image in each **item** div which is dynamically getting populated. Now on carousel play i see the div **item** changes with change of active class but what i see is first div **item** content is also visible when the second **item** div is active similarly when 3rd item div gets active 1st and 2nd div items are visible too. Also the **data-pause="hover"** is not working.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div id="custCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#custCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#custCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#custCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php 
        $counttoken = 9;
        $loop = round($arrloop/9);
        $k=0;

        for($j=0;$j<$loop;$j++)
        {       
            if($k==0){$act='active';}else{$act ='';}
            echo '<div class="item '.$act.'">'; 
                for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
                {   
                    $img = $data[$rand_keys[$i]];
                    echo "<a href=".$img[1]."><img src=".$img[2]." alt=".$img[0]." width='100' /></a>";
                }
                $counttoken = $counttoken + 9;
                                $k++;
                echo '</div>';
        }

        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my bad i made an error in my php code to update the for loop. Here below is the updated code and it's working perfect now.

```
<?php 
        $counttoken = 9;
        $loop = round($arrloop/9);
        $k=0;
        $l=0
        for($j=0;$j<$loop;$j++)
        {       
            if($k==0){$act='active';}else{$act ='';}
            echo '<div class="item '.$act.'">'; 
                for($i=$l; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
                {   
                    $img = $data[$rand_keys[$i]];
                    echo "<a href=".$img[1]."><img src=".$img[2]." alt=".$img[0]." width='100' /></a>";
                }
                $l = $l+9;
                $counttoken = $counttoken + 9;
                                $k++;
                echo '</div>';
        }

        ?>
```